# Finding common tangent lines of two circle in spherical surface

Tags: geometry, circles, spherical-coordinates, tangent-line, spherical-trigonometry

I am able to find common tangent lines of two circles in 2D space ( point is `x,y` ).

but the problem is can I use the equation to be used in spherical surfaces ( point is `lat, lon` )? , in the sense that `x` is longitude and `y` is latitude but still using great circle distance as the distance equation between two points

Comment: Interesting problem.  May I ask what have you tried ? Where are you stuck ?

Comment: basically I just followed this https://cp-algorithms.com/geometry/tangents-to-two-circles.html#the-number-of-common-tangents for 2D space, but i am not sure if the result will be correct for spherical space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the problem spatially. Let $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ be the centers of the circles on the surface of the sphere. (They are unit vectors in $\mathbb R^3$). The points $\vec p$ that lie on the first circle satisfy:$$
\lVert \vec p \rVert = 1 \\
\vec p \cdot \vec a = \cos A
$$

$A$ (and $B$) are the angles that describe the size of the given circles.

A great circle is specified by its axis, $\vec v$ (the normal of the plane the great circle lies on). The tangency condition is a constraint on the angle between vector $\vec v$ and vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$: $$
\vec v \cdot \vec a = \pm \sin A\\
\vec v \cdot \vec b = \pm \sin B\\
\lVert \vec v \rVert^2 = 1
$$

Substitute:$$
\vec v=x \vec a+ y \vec b + z (\vec a \times \vec b)\\
x \vec a \cdot \vec a + y \vec a \cdot \vec b = \pm \sin A\\
x \vec a \cdot \vec b + y \vec b \cdot \vec b = \pm \sin B\\
\lVert x \vec a+ y \vec b + z (\vec a \times \vec b) \rVert = 1
$$
Simplifying:
$$
x + y \vec a \cdot \vec b = \pm \sin A\\
x \vec a \cdot \vec b + y = \pm \sin B\\
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \lVert \vec a \times \vec b\rVert^2 + 2xy \vec a \cdot \vec b = 1
$$
The $\pm$ are independent -- they specify which sides of the circles your great circle is tangent to. $$
S_a=\pm \sin A\\
S_b=\pm \sin B\\
x = \frac{S_a - S_b \vec a \cdot \vec b}{1-(\vec a \cdot \vec b)^2}\\
y = \frac{S_b - S_a \vec a \cdot \vec b}{1-(\vec a \cdot \vec b)^2}
$$
You can then solve for $z$, and thus, find $\vec v$